# PowerShell: unexpected output from a less-than comparison

Tags: powershell, if-statement, foreach, comparison-operators

**Editor's note:**

The original form of this question had a well-defined problem that stemmed from accidentally `-le`-comparing a `[string]` LHS with a `[double]` RHS (annotations added):

```
$c = Get-Date (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime() -UFormat %s
$epochseconds=[math]::Round($c)  # $epochseconds is now a [double]

$d = get-childitem C:\scripts\PALO\* -recurse | Select-String -pattern "expiry-epoch"

$e = $d -split "epoch"  # -split always returns *strings*
$certtime = $e[1]       # $certtime is now a [string]
$epochtime = $epochseconds - 2505600  # $epochtime is a [double]

ForEach ($i in $d){
    If ($certtime -le $epochtime) {  # LHS is [string], RHS is [double]
        Write-Output $i
    }
}
```

The OP's later revision (see below), by replacing the original code, accidentally eliminated this problem by first applying a *subtraction* to the `[string]` LHS (during which an *implicit* conversion to a number happens), rendering the existing answer inapplicable.

---

*[The OP's later revision, which should be a *new* question.]*

I am writing a script that is supposed to notify me if the expiry-epoch time of a certificate is within 30 days of expiration.  However, if one file does not match the IF statement then I get no output, if all files match the IF statement then I get the appropriate output.

```
PS C:\scripts> $certtime
 1560350005

PS C:\scripts> $epochtime
1520858749
```

I just updated the code:

```
$c = Get-Date (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime() -UFormat %s
$epochtimes=[math]::Round($c)
$d = get-childitem C:\scripts\PALO\* -recurse | Select-String -pattern "expiry-epoch"
$e=$d -split "epoch"
$certtime=$e[1]
$certexp = $certtime - 2592000

ForEach ($i in $d){
  If ($certexp -le $epochtime) {
   Write-Output $i
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that you meant `If ($epochtime -le $certtime)`

Comment: What do the lines look like in the files that you are pulling the dates from? for instance if there is a space between expiry-epoch and the number then it will be in $certtime which means you are trying to compare a string and a number.

Comment: the lines look like set shared certificate "PALO ALTO SSL NY CERT" expiry-epoch 1560350005

Answer (score 2):

<sup>Note:
* This answer is based on the *original* code in the question.
* There's an additional problem with the original code not addressed below: `$d` is expected to contain *multiple* items, yet only the *1st* item's epoch time is extracted with `$certtime=$e[1]`; this must be moved into the `foreach` loop: `$certtime = [double] ($i -split "epoch")[1]`</sup>

- The `-split` operator always returns *strings*.
- **Typically, it is the *LHS* of PowerShell operators determines the data type used in the  operation**<sup>[1]</sup>
  .

  - In the case at hand, the LHS of `-le` being a `[string]` means that the RHS is quietly *converted* to a string, whatever its original type.

Thus, given that **`$certtime` is a *string*, `$certtime -le $epochtime` performs *lexical* comparison**, which is not your intent.

The solution is to **cast to the desired numerical data type**:

```
# Use [double], because $epochtime is of type [double] in your code.
$certtime = [double] $e[1]
```

Or, directly in the context of your conditional:

```
if ([double] $certtime -le $epochtime) ...
```

---

<sup>[1] There are exceptions: `-` and `/` convert *both* operands from *strings* to *numbers* on demand; e.g., `' 10' - '2'` yields `[int] 8`; by contrast, this does *not* happen with `+` and `*`, which have string-specific semantics (concatenation and replication).

For other LHS types, `+`, `-`, `*` and `/` only succeed if the given type custom-defines these operators via [operator overloading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/overloadable-operators).

Without overloading, the behavior of non-string-coercing operands such as `-eq`, `-lt`, `-gt`, ... depends on whether the LHS type implements *interfaces* such as `IEquatable` and `IComparable`.
Finally, with the *collection*-based `-in` and `-contains` operators, it is the *individual elements* of the *collection-valued operand* that drive the coercion - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77441956/45375).</sup>